# $u=xf(xy)$, show that $xu_{xx}-yu_{xy} = 0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I need to show that:

$$xu_{xx}-yu_{xy} = 0$$

when $$u=xf(xy)$$

So, I did:

$$u_x = xyf_x(xy)+f(xy) \implies $$
$$u_{xx} = xy^2f_{xx}(xy)+2yf_x(xy)$$
and
$$u_{xy} = xf_x(xy)+x^2yf_{xy}(xy)+xf_y(xy)$$

so:

$$xu_{xx} = x^2y^2f_{xx}(xy)+2xyf_x(xy)$$

$$yu_{xy} = x^2y^2f_{xy}(xy)+2xyf_y(xy)$$

but when I take one from another, I don't get $0$. This makes me think that there is a relation that says

$$f_{xx}(xy) = f_{xy}(xy)$$

so they both cancel, but I couldn't find it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your calculation of $u_x$ is wrong. Choose $u(x,y)=f(xy)=c$ then you get $u_x=c$ and that is wrong.

Comment: How do you explain  $u_x = xyf_x(xy)+f(xy)$?

Comment: @miracle173 sorry, I wrote the wrong $u$ function. Please look now.

Comment: Your calculation of $u_x$ is still wrong

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't know why, I also verified in wolfram alpha and it gave me this. I'm using the product rule and then the chain rule. Could you show me how to do?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xf%28xy%29

Comment: In fact it's not only wrong, it makes no sense! Which come to think of it may point the way to what you're missing. You talk about partial derivatives of $f$ here. The function $f$ does not _have_ partial derivatives - it's a function of _one_ variable! The notation $f(xy)$ means $f$ evaluated at $xy$. Not $f$ times $xy$. And not $f(x,y)$.

Comment: There is no $f_{xx}$ or $f_{xy}$ but only an $f'$ or $f''$

Comment: I don't know why you gave that link to WA. Either WA is wrong, which happens, or more likely you input the problem incorrectly. Starting with WA is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, I looked. First, you input a different function. And second, the answer WA gives is not what you're saying you got...

Comment: A good example of why it is important to start with all the booooring definitions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $u:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: Wtf? You had $u=f(xy)$ in the original post. You changed that to $xf(xy)$ just now.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich OP fixed a typo.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. $f$ can't have partial derivatives, because it's a function composed with the function $xy$ from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So now apply the chain rule _correctly_ and see what happens...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks! It worked :)

Comment: So please post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f$ is a sigle variable function, and it is composed with a 2-variable function, say, $w(x,y)=xy$. So $u$ is a 2-variable function.

We first calculate

- $u_x(x,y)=f(xy)+xyf'(xy)$.
- $u_{xx}(x,y)=yf'(xy)+y\left(f'(xy)+xyf''(xy)\right)=2yf'(xy)+xy^2f''(xy)$.
- $u_{xy}(x,y)=xf'(xy)+x\left(f'(xy)+xyf''(xy)\right)=2xf'(xy)+x^2yf''(xy)$.

Now:
\begin{align*}xu_{xx}(x,y)-yu_{xy}(x,y)&=x\left(2yf'(xy)+xy^2f''(xy)\right)-y\left(2xf'(xy)+x^2yf''(xy)\right)\\
&=2xyf'(xy)+x^2y^2f''(xy)-2xyf'(xy)-x^2y^2f''(xy)\\
&=0.\end{align*}